# CRM Connection String Authentication Free

Tags: c#, web-config, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I am currently developing a billing system web application for our company. We are using CRM to get our Accounts and Contacts. I am using entity approach, which CRM provides a huge class of objects. Well so far all of these structure works fine.

Main consideration in our company, since my connection string consist of user authentication, we would like to have authentication free connection string which will allow us to pull information when we needed.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Xrm" connectionString="Url=https://mytestingcompany.api.crm.dynamics.com; Username=emrecengel@MyTestingCompany.onmicrosoft.com; Password=<MyPassword>; Device ID=<DeviceID>; Device Password=<DevicePassword>"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is there any possible way of authenticating to CRM without using any user authentication. Maybe some sort of API Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Authentication in Dynamics CRM is always bound to an user. There is, sadly, no concept of an API-Token, OAuth or something comparable.